# Can't get method (getTest) to return true boolean method result if input matches a number in my array list

Tags: java

I can't seem to get the "The numbers match" result if my input is a number that is in my array list in another class called `SomeNumbers`. If you run it, it will give you the result for it not being a number in the array at the speed of light though.

I am also having a hard time pin pointing where the actual problem is because I can use my debugging tools for whatever reason in jGrasp.

This is the main application that the user would input the number to see if there is a match.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SomeNumbersClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  SomeNumbers testNumbers = new SomeNumbers();

  Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter Integer Value: ");
  int input = userInput.nextInt();

  testNumbers.setNumber(input);

  if (testNumbers.getTest()) {
     System.out.println("The numbers match");
  } else {
     System.out.println("The numbers don't match");
  }

}

}
```

Now this is the class where I call on the `getTest` method to see if the boolean result is true or false. I then have the if statement in the client see if it's true then it will display that there is a match, if not, there is no match.

```
public class SomeNumbers {
       private int[] numbers = { 5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850,         8080152, 4562555, 5552012, 5050552, 7825877, 120255, 1005231, 6545231, 3852082, 7576651,7881200, 4581002};
       private int number;
       private int index = 0;
       private boolean test = true;

       public void setNumber(int input) {
           number = input;
       }

       public boolean getTest(){
           while (index < numbers.length){
               if (number != numbers[index]){
                   test = false;
                   index++;
               } else {
                   test = true;
               }
              }
        return test;
       }
      }
```

Sorry the code kind of got chopped up, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is proper version of getTest function, your problem was because you find match (and set variable test to true), but then you continue search and next number converts "test" to false

```
public boolean getTest()
{
    index = 0;
    while (index < numbers.length)
        if (number != numbers[index])
            index++;
        else
            return true;
    return false;
}
```